# Eliminate gap in Drawable Shape line

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I'm trying to eliminate a gap seen below. The `View`s are right up against each other so it seems that it is something in the drawable. 
I can see that it is related to the `width` of the `stroke` but how can I eliminate this effect?

Note that this is just an MVCE and the actual use case requires that I use a line smaller than the `View` is high.

For the removal of doubt, I will only accept an answer that fixes it in the drawable xml. I don't want a layout driven work around, the layout supplied is just to expose the problem.

[image: Gap]

**drawable/line.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="line">
    <stroke
        android:width="5dp"
        android:color="#ff0000"/>
</shape>
```

**layout/example.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/line">
    </View>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/line">
    </View>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try to put padding=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where does this gap come from in Drawable Shape line?

The class responsible for creating shape drawables is [GradientDrawable.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/caca720/graphics/java/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.java)

Let's take a look at the source code.

In the `draw(Canvas canvas)` method:

```
switch (st.mShape) {
case LINE: {
        RectF r = mRect;
        float y = r.centerY();
        if (haveStroke) {
            canvas.drawLine(r.left, y, r.right, y, mStrokePaint);
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

A line is drawn from `mRect.left` to `mRect.right`

Now let's see where `mRect` is modified.

In the `ensureValidRect()` method:

```
Rect bounds = getBounds();
float inset = 0;
if (mStrokePaint != null) {
    inset = mStrokePaint.getStrokeWidth() * 0.5f;
}
final GradientState st = mGradientState;
mRect.set(bounds.left + inset, bounds.top + inset, bounds.right - inset, bounds.bottom - inset);
```

As you can see an `inset`, equal to half the stroke width, is added.

This is where your gap comes from.

> how can I eliminate this effect?

1. You can add your own negative inset (should be half of your stroke width)

   **drawable/line_inset.xml**

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:drawable="@drawable/line"
      android:insetLeft="-2.5dp"
      android:insetRight="-2.5dp"/>
   ```
2. Consider using a 9-patch drawable

[image: red line 9-patch]

The lines top and left define the stretch areas. You can see that I'm only stretching the empty space.
The lines right and bottom define the content area, in this case, all of the space.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to remove?

Comment: +1 thanks for confirming the relationship to stroke width. That has lead me to one solution, but going to hold out a bit for other suggestions.

Comment: Can't see a way to remove it with `line` shape. Have you considered using a 9-patch drawable instead?

Comment: Good idea. This is what I have currently got as a solution however: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42120798/360211

Comment: Though, can you make a 9 patch that will stretch vertically, while keeping a fixed height part in the centre of the image?

Comment: Yes that's possible, when creating a 9-patch in Android Studio you can select the parts you would like to scale

Comment: Ok, I figured out how to do it in xml. Check it out.

Answer (score 1):

If I wrap in a layer list and item, I can extend `left` and `right`. I don't need to worry about them going further than needed they'll still cropped to the edge. This combats the effect.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:left="-5dp"
        android:right="-5dp"> <!-- negative stroke width -->
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <stroke
                android:width="5dp"
                android:color="#ff0000"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions:

1) Change the shape declared in XML to a rectangle

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="#ff0000"/>
    <size android:width="100dp" android:height="1dp"/>

</shape>
```

Then in your layout

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/line">
    </View>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/line">
    </View>
</LinearLayout>
```

2) Take a different approach, and not create an XML drawable for the line

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"/>
```

**edit**

You say you need the height of the view greater than the size of the line. You could use an image view and the src attribute in combination with the rectangle XML shape to get this effect:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/line">
</ImageView>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/line">
</ImageView>
```

Comment: Thanks but my example is a [MCVE], the actual use case means I need a line.

Comment: Yep that's fair enough! I will have a look

Comment: It's a good fallback and probably what I will be doing if I can't get anywhere.

Comment: It's a very odd problem though, I can't work out why it doesn't work using a line shape! I tried specifying padding in the line.xml resource but to no avail. I've added an alternative solution to my answer, using a rectangle shape.

Comment: Nice try, but the reason I want this is as a `background` for an `ImageView` which has to display another source